# How could I access to a Dictionary objects?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

I have a dictionary parsed from a JSON (more information here [Can't deserialize Dictionary from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071846/cant-deserialize-dictionary-from-json)) and finally could get the parse done. I get an object with this structure shown in the image. How can I access the values from this object curContent? The "natural" way was trying to cast curContent.soportes[0].avisos to Aviso[] but it says it cannot cast from jArray to Aviso[].

[image]

Comment: *it says it cannot cast from jArray to Aviso[].* - please show the code that does not work - i.e. a [mcve].  A screenshot of the code or debugger output should not be used instead, see [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).  See also [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
currContent.soportes[2].Value
```

but this will give you the json string it looks like. You'd need to deserialize that as well

Comment: Don't have .Value method

Comment: Your screenshot shows the Value property is highlighted.